# How to run code after cin in Sublime Text 3

Tags: c++, sublimetext3, mingw, sublimetext

Sublime Text 3 doesn't run code after `cin` on my Windows OS system. c++ code is running smoothly in Visual Studio Code.

What should I do?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int n;
    cout<<"Ente the value of n "<<endl;
    cin>>n;
    cout<<"value of n is="<<n<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

The error is:

```
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe:
cannot open output file
C:\Users\suraj\Desktop\resume\jayalji\background-generator/test.exe:
Permission denied collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
[Finished in 0.6s]
```

Comment: What is the exact compile command? Did you try to remove `C:\Users\suraj\Desktop\resume\jayalji\background-generator/test.exe` manually?

Comment: You can't run interactive programs in Sublime without using something like [Terminus](https://packagecontrol.io/search/Terminus). You can't link because the program is still running from your previous build, stuck in the background waiting for input you can't provide, and windows won't let you replace an executable while the program is running.